# What does _tkinter.TclError mean and how can I resolve the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to create a window using the Tkinter module in Python3.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
```

And I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what OS you're running, python version, tkinter version... It appears to be a local prob - I use this method and it works fine.

Comment: Is this your only code? This sometimes happens when using matplotlib

Comment: Are you running your code remotely, via SSH or VPN?

Comment: @Legorooj I am running Windows 10 Pro, python 3.6.7 and tkinter 8.6. also, I am running this code from a linux terminal using WSL. Not sure if WSL is causing this issue.

Comment: @hegash no I am not using matplotlib, this is my only code.

Comment: @DYZ no, i am running it locally